# Assign ref to an element in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to integrate react-signature-canvas in my Web App. API methods require a ref to the SignatureCanvas as shown in this [example](https://github.com/agilgur5/react-signature-canvas/blob/d449c18b5d3b7e3bda22bdafcc7e9ddba9e51cd7/example/app.js). I am trying to do the same with my NextJS app with this code

```
const Form = ({ ...props }) => {

  const onSubmit = async e => {
        console.log("FOO ", sigPad) // always null
        props.onNextClicked(contact)

    };

let sigPad  = React.createRef();

return (
<form className="newsletter-form form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
    <SignatureCanvas ref={(ref) => { sigPad = ref }} />
    <div className="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" className="default-btn float-right">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
  )
}
export default Form;
```

sigPad is always null when the form is submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a functional componentt you must use `useRef` instead of `React.createRef`, Otherwise on each re-render your ref will be initialized again.

Also assign the ref directly instead of using callback function

```
const Form = ({ ...props }) => {
  let sigPad  = React.useRef(null);
  const onSubmit = async e => {
        console.log("FOO ", sigPad.current) 
        props.onNextClicked(contact)

    };



return (
<form className="newsletter-form form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
    <SignatureCanvas ref={signPad} />
    <div className="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" className="default-btn float-right">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
  )
}
export default Form;
```